# Find an orthonormal basis of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find an orthonormal basis for a plane defined as $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$? I don't know where to start -- not even given dimensions. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given as $ax+by+cz=0$?

Comment: In general: find an arbitrary basis, and apply Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @Arturo: I am not given dimensions, which is part of my confusion.

Comment: What does "a+b+c=0" mean, then? Are a, b, and c constants? Variables? Do you know the dimension of the ambient space?

Comment: @Arturo: a, b, and c are variables (it was given by x_1 x_2 and x_3 in the textbook). Nothing stated about the dimensions.

Comment: @John: You should stick to $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. Those are *clearly* variables, whereas $a$, $b$, and $c$ are usually constants or scalars.

Answer (score 4):

The subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$ is of dimension $n-1$ and has a basis consisting of the vectors
\begin{align*}
&(1,0,-1,0,0,\ldots,0)\\
&(0,1,-1,0,0,\ldots,0)\\
&(0,0,0,1,0,\ldots,0)\\
&(0,0,0,0,1,\ldots,0)\\
&\qquad\qquad\vdots\\
&(0,0,0,0,0,\ldots,1)
\end{align*}
The last $n-3$ vectors are already normal, pairwise orthogonal, and orthogonal to the first two. So all you need to do is orthogonalize $(1,0,-1,0,\ldots,0)$ and $(0,1,-1,0,\ldots,0)$ by using Gram-Schmidt, and then normalize.

The dimension of the ambient space does not matter in the end, except in so far as padding the basis.