# Basis for Given Plane

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have the same question as this:

[Find an orthonormal basis of a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24965/find-an-orthonormal-basis-of-a-plane)

Only thing is I don't like / understand Arturo's explanation.  So I want to find a basis for the plane

$V = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$

I start by picking $v_1 = [1, 0, -1]$ which is in V.  Then I pick $v_2 = [1, -1, 0]$ which is in V but isn't a scalar multiple of $v_1$

Now this plane has dimension 2, so I have a basis.  I can just apply Gram Schmidt to get an orthonormal basis.

Does the above look kosher?

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: Looks kosher to me.

Comment: yup, looks good, so long as you have a good (linear-algebraic) reason why this plane has dimension 2.